# RSpec request spec for post action that includes headers results in parms being dropped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am trying to figure out why I can't use use both params and headers in an request spec.

What works:

```
RSpec.describe  Api::V1::UsersController, :type => :request  do

  before { host! 'api.localhost:3000'}

  let(:params) {
    {
      "user": {
        "identifier_for_vendor": "BD43813E"
      }
    }
  }

  describe 'Post /users' do
    context 'when request is valid' do
      before {
        post api_users_path,
        params: params
      }

      it "is successful" do
        expect(response).to be_successful
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**What does not:**

```
RSpec.describe  Api::V1::UsersController, :type => :request  do

  let(:params) {
    {
      "user": {
        "identifier_for_vendor": "BD43813E"
      }
    }
  }

  let(:headers) {
    {
      "host": "api.localhost:3000",
      "Accept": "application/vnd.domain_name.v1",
      "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
      "X-API-Key": "fake087uakey"
    }
  }

  describe 'Post /users' do
    context 'when request is valid' do
      before {
        post api_users_path,
        params: params,
        headers: headers
      }

      it "successful" do
        expect(response).to be_successful
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above fails, returning the error:

```
  1) Api::V1::UsersController Post /users when request is valid is successful 
     Failure/Error: params.require(:user).permit(:identifier_for_vendor)

     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

The headers are needed due to having to ensure that valid api-keys are included in the request.

Would appreciate feedback on what I am missing. Thank you

**Versions:**

- Ruby version: 2.6.3
- Rails version: 6.0.3.4
- RSpec 3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So issue had to do with how `params` and `headers` objects are created.

**Params:**

- I passed in:

```
  {"user": {"identifier_for_vendor": "OFJPJ"} }
```

- the correct object is:

```
  {:params=>{:user=>{:identifier_for_vendor=>"OFJPJ"}}}
```

**Headers:**

- I passed in:

```
    {
      "host": "api.localhost:3000",
      "Accept": "application/vnd.domain_name.v1",
      "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
      "X-API-Key": "fake087uakey"
    }
```

- the correct object is:

```
{
  "headers" => {
    "host" => "api.localhost:3000", 
    "Accept" => "application/vnd.domain_name.v1", 
    "X-API-Key" => "api_key"
  }
}
```

Final solution looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe  Api::V1::UsersController, :type => :request  do

  describe 'Post /users' do
    context 'when request is valid' do


      before do
        post api_users_path,
        :params => params,
        :headers => headers
      end


      it "is successful" do
        expect(response).to be_successful
      end

      it "returns a data of type user" do
        expect(json_data["type"]).to eq("user")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The key to figuring this out was reading the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#requesting-a-json-response) and realizing the my formatting was wrong.